# Any advice how to implement a character recognizing functionality?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, image-recognition

Let the user write/draw a character on the canvas,and recognize it.

Seems not so easy,is there an open source project for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CellWriter](http://risujin.org/cellwriter/) is one open source handwriting recognition program.

Comment: @user198729: Download box in the top right corner in the Overview section.

Comment: Great stuff!I'll try to understand its algorithm in 2 months:)